# Ignoring path while archiving with TAR

Tags: linux, unix, archiving, tar

I have a file that contain list of files I want to archive with tar.
Let's call it `mylist.txt`

It contains:

```
/path1/path2/file1.txt
/path1/path2/file3.txt
...
/path1/path2/file10.txt
```

What I want to do is to archive this file into a tarball but excluding `/path1/path2/`.
Currently by doing this:

```
tar -cvf allfiles.tar -T mylist.txt
```

preserves the path after unarchiving.

I tried this but won't work too:

```
tar -cvf -C /path1/path2 allfiles.tar -T mylist.txt
```

It archives all the files in `/path1/path2` even those which are not in mylist.txt

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try with the `--exclude` parameter of tar :

```
tar -cvf allfiles.tar -T mylist.txt --exclude=/path1/path2
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. It still won't do. The path still preserved.